# How can I reduce size of a video before uploading it to firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am developing social media app, in which user can upload videos and images. So before uploading the video to the firebase I want to reduce the size of the video so they load faster in the app feed.

Currently I am using below code. Can anyone just show me a way to reduce size of video before uploading it to firebase?

```
if(videoUri != null){
            final StorageReference filereference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(videoUri));

            uploadTask = filereference.putFile(videoUri);
            uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation() {
                @Override
                public Object then(@NonNull Task task) throws Exception {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    return filereference.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        myUrl= downloadUri.toString();

                        Date todayDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                        String date = formatter.format(todayDate);

                        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");

                        String postid = reference.push().getKey();

                        HashMap<String,Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

                        hashMap.put("postid", postid);
                        hashMap.put("type", "video");
                        hashMap.put("postimage", myUrl);
                        hashMap.put("description", description.getText().toString());
                        hashMap.put("publisher", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        hashMap.put("date", date);

                        reference.child(postid).setValue(hashMap);

                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(PostVideoActivity.this , MainActivity.class);
                        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(PostVideoActivity.this , intent);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        finish();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(PostVideoActivity.this , "Failed to post" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                }
            });
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(PostVideoActivity.this , "No video found" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution,
Create a file

```
    File file;
    ProgressDialog dialogUpload;
```

Create Async Task to compress Video size

```
public class VideoCompressAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    Context mContext;

    public VideoCompressAsyncTask(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialogUpload = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialogUpload.setCancelable(false);
        dialogUpload.setMessage("Please wait until the video upload is complete");
        dialogUpload.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... paths) {
        String filePath = null;
        try {
            String path = paths[0];
            String directoryPath = paths[1];
            filePath = SiliCompressor.with(mContext).compressVideo(path, directoryPath);

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return filePath;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String compressedFilePath) {
        super.onPostExecute(compressedFilePath);
        File imageFile = new File(compressedFilePath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer;

        float length = imageFile.length() / 1024f; // Size in KB
        String value;
        if (length >= 1024)
            value = length / 1024f + " MB";
        else
            value = length + " KB";

        String text = String.format(Locale.US, "%s\nName: %s\nSize: %s", getString(R.string.video_compression_complete), imageFile.getName(), value);
        Log.e(TAG, "text: " + text);
        Log.e(TAG, "imageFile.getName() : " + imageFile.getName());
        Log.e(TAG, "Path 0 : " + compressedFilePath);

        try {
            File file = new File(compressedFilePath);
            InputStream inputStream = null;//You can get an inputStream using any IO API
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int bytesRead;
            ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Base64OutputStream output64 = new Base64OutputStream(output, Base64.DEFAULT);
            VideoUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            try {
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    output64.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            output64.close();
            ba1 = output.toString();
            // Here video size is reduce and call your method to upload file on server
            uploadVideoMethod();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

On button click call AsycTask like below

```
new VideoCompressAsyncTask(getActivity()).execute(file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getParent());
```

Note: you may get file from onActivityResult.

Hope this will help you.